# How to implement the same feature in kotlin?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

```
@Override
publick boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
int id=item.getItemId();
if(id==R.id.id_List_1)
  {
    array=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one_array);
    adapted.clear();
    adapted.addAll(array);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
else if(id==R.id.id_List_2)
  { 
    array=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.two_array);
    adapted.clear();
    adapted.addAll(array);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

//How to implement the same feature in kotlin? Android Strudio... I am feeing blue(((((

Comment: Welcome. You'll likely need to provide quite a lot more details before anyone will be able to help you out here. You can check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is full of tips on how to best give us the information we'll need to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

A direct Kotlin conversion would be:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem) : Boolean {
    val id = item.getItemId()
    if (id == R.id.id_List_1) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one_array)
        adapted.clear()
        adapted.addAll(array)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } else if (id == R.id.id_List_1) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.two_array)
        adapted.clear()
        adapted.addAll(array)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    return true
}
```

You could also use `when` which is similar to Java's `switch` to assign a value to `array` :

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem) : Boolean {
    val id = item.getItemId()
    array = when (id) {
        R.id.id_List_1 -> getResources().getStringArray(R.array.one_array)
        R.id.id_List_2 -> getResources().getStringArray(R.array.two_array)
        else -> return true
    }
    adapted.clear()
    adapted.addAll(array)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    return true
}
```

Note: I've added `return true` since it's a function that expects a boolean value.

Comment: overrides nothing, arrays not called, and adapted.clear(),adapted.addAll(array) adapted.notifyDataSetChanged(), not called, unresolved reference adapter

Answer (score 0):

I will share how I did it, in my case I am using the Bottom Navigation, it may help you or others. 
First I set the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener on onCreate, and then I am defining a name to represent my item selected "item". On my bottom navigation I have four Icon/Item so I created the method WHEN to check which one of then is being called. 
By default you need to return a Boolean value, so I am calling a function, depending on the item clicked, where I will do the actions that I need after the click and returning false, because I don't want my icons highlighted when clicked.

`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
      when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.map_mode -> {
          onMapClicked(item); return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
        R.id.tracks_search -> {
          onTracksClicked(); return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
        R.id.exit_search -> {
          onProfileClicked(); return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
        R.id.metric_option -> {
          onMetricClicked(item); return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
      }; return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
    })}`

If you want to highlight then you should return true.You can also create another function to process repeating lines like updateAdapter.